# Wi-Fi Multimedia (WMM) causing a 100ms latency overhead on Android device

Tags: wi-fi, samsung

So the issue is that I have a Samsung M01 (Android 10) which is having a 100ms overhead latency.

Basically pinging the router gives me a average of 110ms of latency.

So after going around tweaking many settings I finally isolated the problem to the WMM setting.
The lag only happens when WMM is enabled so disabling it fixes the problem.
The problem with disabling WMM is that after that my router only goes at a extremely slow 14Mbps [Disabling WMM causes Wi-Fi Speeds to drop to 14Mbps](https://superuser.com/questions/1625684/disabling-wmm-causes-wi-fi-speeds-to-drop-to-14mbps)

Also another thing I noticed is that this latency overhead only happens when I am connected to a mobile tower (tested by enabling airplane mode )

The latency was monitored while I was playing a game, Downloading some files on a Wi-Fi call and it doesn't go below 100ms. But there are some random times when it starts behaving properly and gives me a latency of 2 to 5ms

Note : The ping monitoring was done by pinging in the local network.
This problem only occurs on my Samsung android device (It also occurs on another Samsung device (Samsung On7 Pro Android 5) but not on the Lenovo device I own). This doesn't occur on any PC/Laptops I have access to.

So does anyone have any suggestion on how to fix this issue?
Thanks in advance.